# How to get the my system's IP address

Tags: php, ip

How do I get my system's IP address?

I am using `$ip_address=$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];`, but it returns my localhost IP address instead of my system's IP address.

Comment: Is your server run on you local machine? ...cause then it will give you the same IP address.

Comment: Check out http://www.suite101.com/content/socket-programming-gethostbyname-a19557

Comment: i am accessing webserver via Internet and not via local network

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing a local server, then your local IP address is the remote IP. PHP is giving you the correct response.

If you want to know your IP address to the rest of the internet, go to Google and type "what is my ip".

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

See the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for a full list of stuff you might find in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Comment: @Ginamin: the OP *is* looking for the server address, *not* the remote address.  That's the reason his code isn't returning the address he expects it to.

Comment: hmm... seems to me he is looking for remote address. "how do i get my system ip address" and "but it return my localhost ip address instead of my system ip" to me seems to point to remote address, but no worries. He has both answers in here now :)

Answer (score 1):

This function will determine the real IP address:

```
function ipCheck() {
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    }
    else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: i am access my local server so it returns the server ip only not my sysytem ip. is it any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

A late reply but I hope it still might be able to help someone. I needed system ip for a project so I quickly scrapped up a custom function using regular expressions. It works on ubuntu linux (and technically should work on any distro/version of linux).

```
function getLocalIp(){
    $output = shell_exec('/sbin/ifconfig');        
    preg_match("/inet?[[:space:]]?addr:([0-9.]+)/", $output, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]))
        $ip = $matches[1];
    else
        $ip = 0;
    return $ip;
}
```

It requires:

- making a system call using shell_exec.
- using regular expressions to find the value of internal ip address.

*If you happen to create something similar for windows or improve the functionality of this function, please share your code with the rest of us.*