# how t0 i get the local system Ip Address using PHP

Tags: php

i am accessing webserver via Internet and not via local network then how to i get the ip address of my local system i am already try this with

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = <?php echo $_SERVER['GATEWAY_INTERFACE']; ?> <br>
SERVER_ADDR = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?> <br>
SERVER_NAME = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?> <br>
SERVER_SOFTWARE = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']; ?> <br>
SERVER_PROTOCOL = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']; ?> <br>
REQUEST_METHOD = <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; ?> <br>
REQUEST_TIME = <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; ?> <br>
QUERY_STRING = <?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?> <br>
DOCUMENT_ROOT = <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> <br>
HTTP_ACCEPT = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; ?> <br>
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET']; ?> <br>
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']; ?> <br>
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; ?> <br>
HTTP_CONNECTION = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']; ?> <br>
HTTP_HOST = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?> <br>
HTTP_REFERER = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?> <br>
HTTP_USER_AGENT = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?> <br>
HTTPS = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTPS']; ?> <br>
REMOTE_ADDR = <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?> <br>
REMOTE_HOST = <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']; ?> <br>
REMOTE_PORT = <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']; ?> <br>
SCRIPT_FILENAME = <?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; ?> <br>
SERVER_ADMIN = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']; ?> <br>
SERVER_PORT = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; ?> <br>
SERVER_SIGNATURE = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']; ?> <br>
PATH_TRANSLATED = <?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']; ?> <br>
SCRIPT_NAME = <?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?> <br>
REQUEST_URI = <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> <br>
PHP_AUTH_DIGEST = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST']; ?> <br>
PHP_AUTH_USER = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; ?> <br>
PHP_AUTH_PW = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']; ?> <br>
AUTH_TYPE = <?php echo $_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']; ?> <br>


( and )

<html>
<head>
 <title>What is my IP address?</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
        $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
echo "Your Proxy IPaddress is : ".$pipaddress. "(via $ipaddress)" ;
    } else {
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but no use it just give the server Ip. Please guide me

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will give the client's IP address. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Copy of link below. You previously asked this and no one could answer. Perhaps you could clarify exactly what you are looking for and what is going on?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447716/how-to-get-the-my-system-ip-address/4447734#4447734

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will not work on load balanced sites. For that, and other different situations, use this class:

http://brettic.us/code/php-codeigniter-remote-ip-from-load-balancer/

```
    class RemoteIP
{
 function ip_address()
 {
  if ($this->ip_address !== FALSE)
  {
   return $this->ip_address;
  }

  if ($this->server('HTTP_X_CLIENTIP'))
  {
    $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLIENTIP'];
  }
  elseif ($this->server('REMOTE_ADDR') AND $this->server('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
  {
    $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  }
  elseif ($this->server('REMOTE_ADDR'))
  {
    $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  elseif ($this->server('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
  {
    $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  }
  elseif ($this->server('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
  {
    $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }

  if ($this->ip_address === FALSE)
  {
   $this->ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
   return $this->ip_address;
  }

  if (strstr($this->ip_address, ','))
  {
   $x = explode(',', $this->ip_address);
   $this->ip_address = end($x);
  }

  if ( ! $this->valid_ip($this->ip_address))
  {
   $this->ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
  }

  return $this->ip_address;
 }
}
```